# Notes for different Signers DocuSign for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Using docusign for salesforce. Sending work documents with tags to be sent for signature. I am trying to add notes for different signers,

Example: Signer 1 = please check the funds before signing
signer 2 = please check the venue

Below is the code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 

//DocuSign Template
var DST=''; 
//Adding Notes & Attachments
var LA='1';
//Custom Recipient List
var CRL='Email~test_1@gmail.com;FirstName~user;LastName~1;Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1,Email~test_2@gmail.com;LastName~user2;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
//Custom Contact Role Map
var CCRM='Signer 1~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2';
//Custom Contact Type Map
var CCTM='Signer 1~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2';
//Custom Email Subject
var CES='{!CustomObject__c.Id} - Please eSign Vocus Sales Agreement';
//Custom Email Message
var CEM='I am sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link below.';
//Custom Envelop from Docusign
var DST = '00000000-33F0-4A8C-A8B2-00000000000';
var CCNM = 'Signer 1~please check the funds before signing,Signer 2~please check the venue';


//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!CustomObject__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

But i am not able to get the notes for the signer. Could anyone help me understand how i could achieve it.

Thanks in-advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a note for one or more of the recipients by updating the **CRL** parameter to specify the note(s) using the **RecipientNote** keyword. For example:

```
var CRL='Email~test_1@gmail.com;FirstName~user;LastName~1;Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1;RecipientNote~Hello Signer 1,Email~test_2@gmail.com;LastName~user2;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2;RecipientNote~Hello Signer 2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
```

See the **CRL** parameter description within the DocuSign for Salesforce Admin Guide (pages 27-29: https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Administrator_Guide.pdf) for details about **RecipientNote**. Amongst other things, it describes how you can include commas, semicolons, and line-breaks in the note:

```
The other fields are strings and must not contain either ‘,’ 
(comma) or ‘;’ (semicolon), since those two characters 
are used to parse the CRL string. Since commas and 
semicolons could be used in the RecipientNote, you can 
specify _COMMA_ or _SEMI_ to embed a ‘,’ or ‘;’ in the 
note. ‘\\n’ can be used to embed a carriage return in the 
note.
```

Comment: Cant we use CCNM which is one of the parameters in Custom button logic?

Comment: That certainly may be another option (depending on which other parameters you are using). Your question shows the CRL parameter -- if you're using the CRL parameter, you can specify Recipient Notes using the method I've described.